# How do you reference a button inside of its actionlistener?

Tags: java, reference, jframe, actionlistener

I'm just starting to get used to listeners but I am still kind of new to working with them. I need to reference a button inside of its actionlistener to get the text of that button. 
my code I want is:

```
for(int i = 0; i<48; ++i){
        button[i] = new JButton("");
        contentPane.add(button[i]);
        button[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x_marks_the_spot();
                if(button[i].getText().equals("X")){
                    increase_hit();
                }
                else{
                    increase_miss();
                }
            }
        });
```

Obviously I can't do this because [i] doesn't actually exist in the anon portion of code. I am sure there is a way to do this by getting the source, but I can't think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously I can't do this because `[i]` doesn't actually exist in the anon portion of code.

You could do it by copying `i` into a `final` variable:

```
// Make a final copy of loop variable before making the listener
final tmpI = i;
...
// Use your final variable instead of `i` inside the listener
if(button[tmpI].getText().equals("X")){
```

However, this is not the most efficient way of doing it, because each button would need its own listener object, with the reference to `tmpI` stored inside the code.

You can create a single `ActionListener` object, and share it among all buttons, like this:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x_marks_the_spot();
        JButton sender = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if(sender.getText().equals("X")){
            increase_hit();
        } else{
            increase_miss();
        }
    }
};
for(int i = 0; i<48; ++i){
    button[i] = new JButton("");
    contentPane.add(button[i]);
    button[i].addActionListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't use this code exactly, but I needed to see how the source was actually called and then translated to button that could be referenced.

Answer (score 3):

> do this by getting the source

I believe what you want is [ActionEvent.getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource())